# Difference between locations using Core Location

Tags: swift3, core-location

I would like to know what am I doing wrong with getting defference between location. Already counting well traveled distance but also would like to get over and over again information after every 100m as a console log.

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations _locations: [CLLocation]) {

 self._locations = _locations
        let _latestLocation: CLLocation = _locations[_locations.count - 1]
        let _firstLocation: CLLocation = _locations.first!

 if _startLocation == nil {
                _startLocation = _latestLocation
            }

            let _traveledDistance: CLLocationDistance = _latestLocation.distance(from: _startLocation)
            let _distance: CLLocationDistance = _latestLocation.distance(from: _firstLocation)


            print("Distance interval : \(_distance)")
            print("Traveled distance : \(_traveledDistance)")

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mostly, first locations are usually not precise. You can discard a few of them before start updating.

Comment: _distance is all the time 0 in this case ;/